# Campo transient para una Lista en una relación 1 a muchos

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

Tengo una entidad (tabla A) que tiene una relación 1 a N con Tabla B. Ésta lista no tiene porque venir siempre en el objeto (carga Lazy). ¿Podría crear un campo transient para ésta lista? ¿Se pondría la anotación junto a la anotación @oneToMany o hay que crear otro atributo como @Transient que contenga las Lista?

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "TABLA_A")
public class TablaA implements Serializable {


    private static final long serialVersionUID = -6366214404750398932L;

    @Id
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "TABLA_A_SEQ", 
        sequenceName = "TABLA_A_SEQ", allocationSize = 1)
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "TABLA_A_SEQ")
    @Column(name = "ID_TABLA_A", unique = true, nullable = false, 
        insertable = false, updatable = false)
    private Long idTablaA;

    @OneToMany
    @JoinColumn(name ="IdTablaB",referencedColumnName = "idTablaA", nullable = false,
        insertable = false, updatable = false)
    private List<TablaB> listaTablaB; 

    @Transient
    private List<TablaB> listaTransientTablaB;
```

Comment: No acabo de entender la pregunta: si quieres que sea *LAZY* márcala como tal. Los atributos marcados con `@Transient` serán ignorados por JPA

Comment: Es que aunque ponga fetch = FetchType.LAZY en el campo me sigue trayendo todo de la base de datos

Comment: Sólo si llamas al get

Comment: La lista transient se mandaría al front en un elemento desplegable. Dependiendo de si se clicka o no en el desplegable traerlo desde el back. Adjunto imagen.

Answer (score 3):

Creo que no has entendido del todo lo que significa *@Transient* para Hibernate, así que te pongo un ejemplo:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "usuario")
public class Usuario {

    @Id
    private Integer getId() {...};

    private String getNombre() {...};

    private String getApellidos() { ... };

    @Transient
    private String getNombreCompleto {
        return nombre + " " + apellidos;
    }

}
```

Imagina que tienes una clase así, con tus `getters` y `setters` para que Hibernate sepa qué campos tiene que persistir. Pero, por comodidad, quieres tener un método extra que obtenga información en otro formato o derivada de la ya obtenida. Ese campo no existe en la base de datos y quieres dejar claro a Hibernate que no tiene que rellenarlo en tu entidad ni en tu base de datos. Eso es lo que hace la anotación *@Transient*, decirle a Hibernate "este campo debe ser ignorado al leer o al escribir datos".

Por otro lado, que un campo sea anotado como *LAZY* lo que hace es que la información sólo se obtenga cuando sea necesaria, es algo como lo siguiente:

```
List<Hijo> getHijos() {
    if (this.hijos == null) {
        this.hijos = leerHijos();
    }
    return this.hijos;
}
```

Mientras no llames al método `get...`, Hibernate no hará la búsqueda en la base de datos, y así te ahorras la consulta.

Comment: Jackson no serializa objetos LAZY...

Comment: Tienes dos soluciones a eso: crear un DTO (que evita acoplamiento) o usar [jackson-datatype-hibernate](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-datatype-hibernate)